# Extracting logs send over SocketAppender via LogEvent Object

Tags: java, object, logging, log4j2

So this is my Configuration file or **log4j2.properties** file

```
#Socket Appender
appender.socket.type=Socket
appender.socket.name=Socket_Appender
appender.socket.host=10.176.250.5
appender.socket.port=9000
appender.socket.layout.type=SerializedLayout
appender.socket.connectTimeoutMillis=2000
appender.socket.reconnectionDelayMillis=1000
appender.socket.protocol=TCP
#Loggers
logger.socket.name=atom
logger.socket.level=debug
logger.socket.appenderRefs=socket
logger.socket.appenderRef.socket.ref=Socket_Appender
```

Next i have two classes LogSender and LogListener

## LogSender

Its Job is to send the logs via SocketAppender.

> What is sent over the Stream is an LogEvent Object.

```
public class LogSender {

public static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("atom");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.trace("Error 1");
    LOG.debug("Error 2");
    LOG.info("Error 3");
    LOG.warn("Error 4");
    LOG.error("Error 5");
    LOG.fatal("Error 6");
    }
}
```

## LogListener

This is supposed to receive the LogEvent Object which is sent over the stream.
LogListener is using a ObjectInputStream and saving the

```
LogEvent event = null;
private Socket socket1 = null;
private ServerSocket ss = null;
PrintWriter sspw=null;
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
try {
//Creating Socket and making it listen to a specific port, receiving through streams.
//Servers socket creation and waiting
        ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
        socket1 = ss.accept();

        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket1.getInputStream()));

        event = (LogEvent) objectInputStream.readObject();
        System.out.println(event.getLoggerName());
        System.out.println(event.getLevel());
        System.out.println(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
        objectInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> **Output**
>
> atom
>
> DEBUG
>
> Error 2

Output is the name of the Logger as expected. Which means we are receiving a LogEvent Object and able to extract the loggers info. I am also able to receive the actual log messages but only one of the levels popup i.e. DEBUG level.

**I want all other levels too. How would i go ahead and do that ?**

I am very new to Log4j2 and i feel like i have missed something(just a gut feeling) in understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get the first log (TRACE) because in your config file `log4j2.properties`, you have `logger.socket.level=debug`, but you should have `logger.socket.level=trace` to also enable the level TRACE.

Concerning the other logs, you should run your listener code in a loop: right now you're reading only the first log.

I didn't test this code but it should look like:

```
LogEvent event = null;
private Socket socket1 = null;
private ServerSocket ss = null;
PrintWriter sspw=null;
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
try {
        //Creating Socket and making it listen to a specific port, receiving through streams.
        //Servers socket creation and waiting
        ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
        socket1 = ss.accept();

        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket1.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {  
            event = (LogEvent) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(event.getLoggerName());
            System.out.println(event.getLevel());
            System.out.println(event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (objectInputStream != null) {
        objectInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: **So** , yes it worked,  But i don't understand how.

Comment: I end up getting EOFException which i don't understand

Comment: If you got this exception in the code showed above, then it should mean that the other party (the app that is sending logs) has terminated the connection (or maybe a network issue between the two parties). I guess you can put this whole code inside another loop to re-connect automatically/periodically in case of EOFException